# How to safely flush a buffer from a different thread, without synchronized methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

There are multiple threads, say B, C and D, each writing small packets of data to a buffer at a high frequency. They own their buffer and nobody else ever writes to it. Writing must be as fast as possible, and I've determined that using `synchronized` makes it unacceptably slow.

The buffers are simply byte arrays, along with the index of the first free element:

```
byte[] buffer;
int index;

public void write(byte[] data) {
    // some checking that the buffer won't overflow... not important now
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, index, data.length);
    index += data.length;
}
```

Every once in a while, thread A comes along to flush everybody's buffer to a file. It's okay if this part has some overhead, so using `synchronized` here is no problem.

Now the trouble is, that some other thread might be writing to a buffer, while thread A is flushing it. This means that two threads attempt to write to `index` around the same time. That would lead to data corruption, which I would like to prevent, but *without* using `synchronized` in the `write()` method.

I've got the feeling that, using the right order of operations and probably some `volatile` fields, this must be possible. Any bright ideas?

Comment: after finish writing, change any volatile (even static will do), or if you extra brave use Undafe.putXXXVolatile, but you need to update both together. i.e. the object holding the structure itself must be updated, incl. reallocating the array.

Comment: I am not familiar on this ,  synchronized uses double check lock, to improve further readwritelock might improve performance.

Comment: @bestsss: Sorry, I don't follow. Could you maybe post an answer, perhaps include some code?

Comment: See my updated answer Thomas...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you *tried* a solution which uses synchronization, and found it doesn't perform well enough? You say you've determined that it's unacceptably slow - how slow was it, and do you already have a performance budget? Normally, obtaining an uncontested lock is extremely cheap, so I wouldn't *expect* it to be a problem.

There may well be some clever lock-free solution - but it's likely to be *significantly* more complicated than just synchronizing whenever you need to access shared data. I understand that lock-free coding is all the rage, and scales beautifully when you can do it - but if you've got one thread interfering with another's data, it's very hard to do it safely. Just to be clear, I like using lock-free code when I can use high-level abstractions created by experts - things like the Parallel Extensions in .NET 4. I just don't like working with *low-level* abstractions like volatile variables if I can help it.

Try locking, and benchmark it. Work out what performance is acceptable, and compare the performance of a *simple* solution with that goal.

Of course, one option is redesigning... does the flushing *have* to happen actively in a different thread? Could the individual writer threads not just hand off the buffer to the flushing thread (and start a different buffer) periodically? That would make things a lot simpler.

EDIT: Regarding your "flush signal" idea - I'd been thinking along similar lines. But you need to be careful about how you do it so that the signal can't get lost even if one thread takes a long time to process whatever it's doing. I suggest you make thread A publish a "flush counter"... and each thread keeps its own counter of when it last flushed.

EDIT: Just realized this is Java, not C# - updated :)

Use `AtomicLong.incrementAndGet()` to increment from thread A, and `AtomicLong.get()` to read from the other threads. Then in each thread, compare whether you're "up to date", and flush if necessary:

```
private long lastFlush; // Last counter for our flush
private Flusher flusher; // The single flusher used by all threads 

public void write(...)
{
    long latestFlush = flusher.getCount(); // Will use AtomicLong.get() internally
    if (latestFlush > lastFlush)
    {
        flusher.Flush(data);
        // Do whatever else you need
        lastFlush = latestFlush; // Don't use flusher.getCount() here!
    }
    // Now do the normal write
}
```

Note that this assumes you only ever need to check for flushing in the Write method. Obviously that may not be the case, but hopefully you can adapt the idea.

Comment: Jon, I disagree, lock-free algorithms are a true adventure on their right own. I'd advise anyone enthusiastic to try 'em. Understanding why and how definitely improves one's skill. As for the question, writing to a single volatile will do.

Comment: @bestsss: Sure, lock-free programming is fun and interesting... but it's also very hard, and I'd be reluctant to implement my own lock-free algorithms in production. As for "writing to a single volatile" - you'll need to provide a lot more detail than that, I suspect. I look forward to your answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, I have tried. It slows down my program by about a factor of two, which is a real problem, because it distorts the measurements I'm trying to take. The flushing has to be done on a different thread, because all buffers are written to a single file, and this happens at the discretion of thread A (i.e. can't wait until a `write()` has happened on the other threads). I might be able to send a "flush" signal to the other threads, though, which would indeed be easier. Thanks!

Comment: @bestsss: I, for two, also fail to see how a single volatile would do the trick. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Jon Skeet *I'd be reluctant to implement my own lock-free algorithms in production*  Someone has to do, you can't wait for the big-boys to do the code; I mean I do implement lock-free code in production whenever I can.

Comment: @bestsss: I can definitely wait for the big boys (the concurrency experts) to implement the low-level side, and build us higher level abstractions. I'm happy to use those abstractions (TPL etc) within my code, but it's too hard to do reliably at a low level unless you're *really* an expert.

Comment: @Thomas: I have an idea for the "flush" signal which I'll edit into the answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, you can't use a Flusher w/o having a lock, BlockingQueue, Semaphore, etc. For a brief moment you need to hold a lock in order to signal.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, that's an interesting point (the waiting one) and I support it, however in my understand the site should not shun any learning experience otherwise there will be no newly born 'experts'. People read: "dont do that", "look for alternatives", etc and they go that way, never try b/c it's scary or dangerous. I don't know what qualifies an expert, java concurrency had numerous bugs fixed, many of them spotted by non-experts.

Comment: @bestsss: The `Flusher.Flush(data)` method would need some synchronization - but the rest wouldn't. No need for a lock in order to signal - that's the point of using `Interlocked` for the flush count.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, you mean each thread holds a "lastFlush" like in a ThreadLocal?

Comment: @bestsss: Not in a ThreadLocal, but in its own object. I'm assuming that each non-flushing thread has its own buffer state - and lastFlush ends up as part of that state, effectively.

Comment: @Jon, I didn't mean implemented by a threadLocal class but an instance per thread which is effectively threadLocal, in C# you can even "declare"like that (asked since the interlocked part was C#)

Answer (score 1):

You can use volatile alone to safely read/write to a buffer (if you have only one writer) however, only one thread can safely flush the data.   To do this you can use a ring buffer.

I would add to @Jon's comment that this is significantly more complicated to test. e.g. I had one "solution" which worked for 1 billion messages consistently one day but kept breaking the next because the box was more loaded.

With synchronized your latency should be below 2 micro-seconds. With Lock, you could get this down to 1 micro-second. with busy waiting on a volatile you can get this down to 3-6 ns per byte (The time it takes to transfer data between threads becomes important)

Note: as the volume of data increases the relative cost of the lock becomes less important. e.g. if you are typically writing 200 bytes or more I wouldn't worry about the difference.

One approach I take is to use the Exchanger with two direct ByteBuffers and avoid writing any data in the critical path (i.e. only write the data after I have processed everything and it doesn't matter so much)

Comment: It's typically only a few bytes, so the overhead really adds up. I understand that it's difficult to ensure that it is correct, which is why I'm asking all these bright people on SO! I hadn't heard about the `Exchanger` class; I'm not sure it'll help here, but I have another situation where it might come in handy, thanks! These timings you mention, are these on a PC? Because I'm on an Android mobile device, with a different JRE, and I suspect that makes a difference.

Comment: An android phone rather than a PC running Java should make a big difference. So I suspect you will have to try different possibilities to see what works best.

Comment: You might not have the option of busy waiting unless you have plenty of free cores. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Volatile Variables And A Circular Buffer**

Use a circular buffer, and make the flushing thread "chase" the writes around the buffer instead of resetting the index to zero after each flush. This allows writes to occur during a flush without any locking.

Use two volatile variables - `writeIndex` for where the writing thread is up to, and `flushIndex` for where the flushing thread is up to. These variables are each updated by only one thread, and can be read atomically by the other thread. Use these variables to keep the threads constrained to separate sections of the buffer. Do not allow the flushing thread to go past where the writing thread is up to (i.e. flush an unwritten part of the buffer). Do not allow the writing thread to go past where the flushing thread is up to (i.e. overwrite an unflushed part of the buffer).

Writing thread loop:

- Read `writeIndex` (atomic)
- Read `flushIndex` (atomic)
- Check that this write will not overwrite unflushed data
- Write to the buffer
- Calculate the new value for `writeIndex`
- Set `writeIndex` (atomic)

Flushing thread loop:

- Read `writeIndex` (atomic)
- Read `flushIndex` (atomic)
- Flush the buffer from `flushIndex` to `writeIndex - 1`
- Set `flushIndex` (atomic) to the value that was read for `writeIndex`

But, **WARNING:** for this to work, the buffer array elements might also need to be volatile, which you can't do in Java (yet). See http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html

Nevertheless, here's my implementation (changes are welcome):

```
volatile int writeIndex = 0;
volatile int flushIndex = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[268435456];

public void write(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    int localWriteIndex = writeIndex; // volatile read
    int localFlushIndex = flushIndex; // volatile read

    int freeBuffer = buffer.length - (localWriteIndex - localFlushIndex +
        buffer.length) % buffer.length;

    if (data.length > freeBuffer)
        throw new Exception("Buffer overflow");

    if (localWriteIndex + data.length <= buffer.length) {
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, localWriteIndex, data.length);
        writeIndex = localWriteIndex + data.length;
    }
    else
    {
        int firstPartLength = buffer.length - localWriteIndex;
        int secondPartLength = data.length - firstPartLength;

        System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, localWriteIndex, firstPartLength);
        System.arraycopy(data, firstPartLength, buffer, 0, secondPartLength);

        writeIndex = secondPartLength;
    }
}

public byte[] flush() {
    int localWriteIndex = writeIndex; // volatile read
    int localFlushIndex = flushIndex; // volatile read

    int usedBuffer = (localWriteIndex - localFlushIndex + buffer.length) %
        buffer.length;
    byte[] output = new byte[usedBuffer];

    if (localFlushIndex + usedBuffer <= buffer.length) {
        System.arraycopy(buffer, localFlushIndex, output, 0, usedBuffer);
        flushIndex = localFlushIndex + usedBuffer;
    }
    else {
        int firstPartLength = buffer.length - localFlushIndex;
        int secondPartLength = usedBuffer - firstPartLength;

        System.arraycopy(buffer, localFlushIndex, output, 0, firstPartLength);
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, output, firstPartLength, secondPartLength);

        flushIndex = secondPartLength;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Nope, the index variable is only set by the writing thread, and the unflushed index variable is only set by the flushing thread.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, that makes it much clearer. This is simple enough, and I think it should work correctly. I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Thomas See edits - volatiles still use locks, and the buffer elements being non-volatile might make this whole approach moot :(

Comment: `volatile` variables **are not** "synchronized on themselves", and the page you link to clearly states this fact. The way I understand it, `volatile` mainly affects caching and prevents out-of-order writes.

Comment: @Joe Daley, the above is incorrect since you need synchronized flushers, also 2 concurrent writes will mess up the data badly. They can write over the same data, incorrectly update. You can't use volatile w/o CAS and ensure any ordering/atomic execution. I can show how to do it w/ CAS and writeIndexes but reading the data ain't so simple.

Comment: @Thomas Okay, I deleted that bit.

Comment: @bestsss When could 2 concurrent writes occur? The buffer is only modified by the writing thread.

Comment: @Joe Dalye: *There are multiple threads, say B, C and D, each writing small packets of data to a buffer at a high frequency.* The wording... if 2 concurrent `write()` occur (B/C/D threads), the entire stuff dies. I show you the write race: 2 threads read writeIndex and store it to localWriteIndex.  Then write the data overlappingly and update the writeIndex, you have to CAS the write index BEFORE any modification. However that wrecks the reading since the data will not be copied till that write index. I hope you get the problem

Comment: @bestsss I understood each thread B, C, D has its own buffer and index variables. Perhaps Thomas can clarify. I agree this does not work if multiple writing threads share the same buffer and index variables.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic;    

byte[] buffer;
AtomicInteger index;

public void write(byte[] data) {
    // some checking that the buffer won't overflow... not important now
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, index, data.length);
    index.addAndGet(data.length);
}

public int getIndex() {
    return index.get().intValue();
}
```

otherwise the lock classes in the java.util.concurrent.lock package are more lightweight than the synchronized keyword...

so:

```
byte[] buffer;
int index;
ReentrantReadWriteLock lock;

public void write(byte[] data) {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    // some checking that the buffer won't overflow... not important now
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, index, data.length);
    index += data.length;
    lock.writeLock.unlock();
}
```

and in the flushing thread:

```
object.lock.readLock().lock(); 
// flush the buffer      
object.index = 0;                     
object.lock.readLock().unlock();
```

**UPDATE:**
The pattern you describe for reading and writing to the buffer will not benefit from using a ReadWriteLock implementation, so just use a plain ReentrantLock:

```
final int SIZE = 99;
byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];
int index;
// Use default non-fair lock to maximise throughput (although some writer threads may wait longer)
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

// called by many threads
public void write(byte[] data) {
    lock.lock();
    // some checking that the buffer won't overflow... not important now        
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, index, data.length);
    index += data.length;
    lock.unlock();
}

// Only called by 1 thread - or implemented in only 1 thread:
public byte[] flush() {
    byte[] rval = new byte[index];
    lock.lock();
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, rval, 0, index);
    index = 0;
    lock.unlock();
    return rval;
}
```

As you describe usage as many write threads with a single reader/flusher thread, a ReadWriteLock is not neccessary, Infact I beleive it is more heavyweight than a simple ReentrantLock (?). ReadWriteLocks are useful for many reader threads, with few write threads - the opposite of the situation you describe.

Comment: `AtomicInteger` might be helpful here, but I think the way you are using it does not cover all bases. Your `ReentrantReadWriteLock` solution would work; I'll see if that is fast enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas, you wanted NOT to block in the write, read/write locks do block the writer if there are any reading locks held.

Comment: I have no problem with blocking, as long as it's fast enough :) `synchronized` is not fast enough.

Comment: I only used AtomicInteger for illustration of non-blocking thread safety, as you only asked about access to the index variable. Also, I made slight error in lock example, use readLock() in flushing thread, as witeLock().lock() will block until readLock is released (if held of course), which i think is what you want. Updated answer: also, why increment index by data length? just = would be better no?

Comment: ignore last statement in prev comment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Invert control. Rather than having A poll the other threads, let them push.

I suppose [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) might be the most simple thing to go with.

Pseudocode:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> jobs;//here the buffers intended to be flushed are pushed into 
LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]> pool;//here the flushed buffers are pushed into for reuse
```

Writing thread:

```
while (someCondition) {
     job = jobs.take();
     actualOutput(job);
     pool.offer(job);
}
```

Other threads:

```
void flush() {
     jobs.offer(this.buffer);
     this.index = 0;
     this.buffer = pool.poll();
     if (this.buffer == null) 
          this.buffer = createNewBuffer();
}
void write(byte[] data) {
    // some checking that the buffer won't overflow... not important now
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, index, data.length);
    if ((index += data.length) > threshold) 
         this.flush();
}
```

LinkedBlockingQueue basically encapsulates the technical means to pass messages safely between threads.
Not only is it simpler this way round, but it clearly seperates concerns, because the threads that actually generate the output determine when they want to flush their buffers and they are the only ones to maintain their own state.
The buffers that are in both queues present a memory overhead, but that should be acceptable. The pool is unlikely to grow signifficantly bigger than the total number of threads and unless actual output presents a bottleneck, the jobs queue should be empty most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29).

Comment: [Sun already did it.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) But I'm afraid you're missing the point; I _don't_ want to use any synchronization in the `write()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I like the lock-free stuff, it's addictive :). And rest ensured: they remove a lot locking shortcomings, coming w/ some steep learning curve. Still they're and error-prone.

Read few articles, perhaps a book and try it home 1st.
How to handle your case? You can't atomically copy data (and update size), but you can atomically update a reference to that data.
simple way to do it; Note: *you can ALWAYS read from the buffer* w/o holding a lock which is the entire point.

```
final AtomicReference<byte[]> buffer=new AtomicReference<byte[]>(new byte[0]);
void write(byte[] b){
    for(;;){
        final byte[] cur = buffer.get();
        final byte[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(cur, cur.length+b.length);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, cur, cur.length, b.length);
        if (buffer.compareAndSet(cur, copy)){
            break;
        }
            //there was a concurrent write
            //need to handle it, either loop to add at the end but then you can get out of order
            //just as sync
    }
}
```

You actually you can still use a larger byte[] and append to it but I leave the exercise for yourself.

---

**Continued**

I had to write the code in a pinch. A short description follows:
The code is lock-free but not-obstruction free due to use of the CLQ. As you see the code always continues regardless of the conditions taken and practically doesn't loop (busy wait) anywhere besides the CLQ, itself.

Many lock-free algorithms rely on the help of all the threads to properly finish the task(s). 
There might be some mistake but I hope the main idea is sort of clear:

- The algorithm allows many writers, many readers
- If the main `state` cannot be changed so there is a single writer only, append the `byte[]` into a queue.
- Any writer (that succeeded on  the CAS) must attempt to flush the queue prior to writing its own data.
- A reader must check for pending writes and flush them before using the main buffer
- If enlarging (current byte[] not enough) the buffer and the size must be thrown away and new generation of Buffer+Size is to be used. Otherwise only `size` is increased. The operation again requires to hold the lock (i.e. the CAS succeeded)

Please, any feedback is welcome. 
Cheers and hopefully people can warm up to the lock-free structures algorithms.

```
package bestsss.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

//the code uses ConcurrentLinkedQueue to simplify the implementation
//the class is well - know and the main point is to demonstrate the  lock-free stuff
public class TheBuffer{
    //buffer generation, if the room is exhaused need to update w/ a new refence
    private static class BufGen{
        final byte[] data;
        volatile int size;

        BufGen(int capacity, int size, byte[] src){
            this.data = Arrays.copyOf(src, capacity);
            this.size  = size;
        }

        BufGen append(byte[] b){
            int s = this.size;
            int newSize = b.length+s;
            BufGen target;
            if (newSize>data.length){
                int cap = Integer.highestOneBit(newSize)<<1;
                if (cap<0){
                    cap = Integer.MAX_VALUE;                    
                }               
                target = new BufGen(cap, this.size, this.data);             
            } 
            else if(newSize<0){//overflow 
                throw new IllegalStateException("Buffer overflow - over int size");
            } else{ 
                target = this;//if there is enough room(-service), reuse the buffer
            }
            System.arraycopy(b, 0, target.data, s, b.length);
            target.size = newSize;//'commit' the changes and update the size the copy part, so both are visible at the same time
            //that's the volatile write I was talking about
            return target;
        }       
    }

    private volatile BufGen buffer = new BufGen(16,0,new byte[0]);

    //read consist of 3 volatile reads most of the time, can be 2 if BufGen is recreated each time
    public byte[] read(int[] targetSize){//ala AtomicStampedReference
        if (!pendingWrites.isEmpty()){//optimistic check, do not grab the look and just do a volatile-read
            //that will serve 99%++ of the cases
            doWrite(null, READ);//yet something in the queue, help the writers
        }
        BufGen buffer = this.buffer;
        targetSize[0]=buffer.size;
        return  buffer.data;
    }
    public void write(byte[] b){
        doWrite(b, WRITE);
    }

    private static final int FREE = 0;
    private static final int WRITE = 1;
    private static final int READ= 2;

    private final AtomicInteger state = new AtomicInteger(FREE);
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<byte[]> pendingWrites=new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<byte[]>();
    private void doWrite(byte[] b, int operation) {
        if (state.compareAndSet(FREE, operation)){//won the CAS hurray!
            //now the state is held "exclusive"
            try{
                //1st be nice and poll the queue, that gives fast track on the loser
                //we too nice 
                BufGen buffer = this.buffer;
                for(byte[] pending; null!=(pending=pendingWrites.poll());){
                    buffer = buffer.append(pending);//do not update the global buffer yet
                }
                if (b!=null){
                    buffer = buffer.append(b);
                }
                this.buffer = buffer;//volatile write and make sure any data is updated
            }finally{
                state.set(FREE);
            }
        } 
        else{//we lost the CAS, well someone must take care of the pending operation 
            if (b==null)
                return;

            pendingWrites.add(b);           
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //usage only, not a test for conucrrency correctness
        TheBuffer buf = new TheBuffer();        
        buf.write("X0X\n".getBytes());
        buf.write("XXXXXXXXXXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n".getBytes());
        buf.write("Hello world\n".getBytes());
        int[] size={0};
        byte[] bytes = buf.read(size);
        System.out.println(new String(bytes, 0, size[0]));
    }
}
```

---

#### Simplistic case

Another far simpler solution that allows many writers but *single* reader. It postpones the writes into a CLQ and the reader just reconstructs 'em. The construction code is omiitted this time.

```
package bestsss.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class TheSimpleBuffer {
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<byte[]> writes =new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<byte[]>();
    public void write(byte[] b){
        writes.add(b);
    }

    private byte[] buffer;
    public byte[] read(int[] targetSize){
        ArrayList<byte[]> copy = new ArrayList<byte[]>(12);
        int len = 0;
        for (byte[] b; null!=(b=writes.poll());){
            copy.add(b);
            len+=b.length;
            if (len<0){//cant return this big, overflow 
                len-=b.length;//fix back;
                break;
            }
        }
        //copy, to the buffer, create new etc....
        //...

        ///
        targetSize[0]=len;
        return buffer; 
    }

}
```

Comment: While this technically solves the problem without using locking, it looks like a [Schlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) to me... so it's slower than simply using `synchronized` in the long run.

Comment: about to get the non-blocking append :)

Comment: @bestsss: This is what you describe as "As for the question, writing to a single volatile will do."? Looks a bit more complicated than that to me...

Comment: @Jon, the algo is for many reader/many writers, many writers/single reader requires just a CLQ alike (i.e. indeed a volatile CAS) structure and the reader reconstructs the writes.

Comment: @bestsss: My point is that what started off sounding very simple ("writing to a single volatile") ends up being very complicated, and hard to verify. It would take me a long time to really make sure this is safe. I'm not saying it's not, just that I try to avoid this complexity where possible.

Comment: Holy crap, that's a lot of code! :O I'm with Jon Skeet here; if it has to be this hard, I'll have to find another way...

Comment: @Thomas, well, I guess I will never become a mediocre (at best) teacher. People just get intimidated . You can still have a look at the 2nd simplistic idea if that suits your needs. Good luck!